# Using CFMAIL tag to send emails with an image

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cfmail

My code is as below,

```
<cfmail
    to="sender@xyz.com"
    from="receiver@xyz.com"
    subject="email with image">

    <img src="cid:pClip" width="350" height="85" alt="" />

    there is an image above this msg.

    <cfmailparam file="#ExpandPath('PaperClip.jpg')#"
        contentid="pClip"
        disposition="inline" />

  </cfmail>
```

I got this to work, however the problem now is image is showing up as an attachment, **NOT** inline (mail client : Outlook 2010). Any suggestions?

Comment: I already had the below solution (type="html") in my code, but your IMG embed code helped me solve the attachment issue in Outlook.  Your question solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to add a type attribute to your cfmail tag

```
<cfmail
    to="sender@xyz.com"
    from="receiver@xyz.com"
    subject="email with image"
    type="html">
```

Comment: yupe that's what missing. Thanks.